# Why doesn't SQLite split this query into two parts automatically?

Tags: caching, sqlite, inner-join

I have two tables to join. TABLE_A (contains column `a`) and TABLE_BC (contains columns `b` and `c`).
There is a condition on TABLE_BC. The two tables are joined by `rowid`.

```
SELECT a, b, c 
FROM main.TABLE_A 
INNER JOIN main.TABLE_BC 
WHERE (b > 10.0 AND c < 10.0) 
ON main.TABLE_A.rowid = main.TABLE_BC.rowid 
ORDER BY a;
```

Alternatively:

```
SELECT a, b, c 
FROM main.TABLE_A AS s1 
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT rowid, b, c 
  FROM main.TABLE_BC 
  WHERE (b > 10.0 AND c < 10.0)
) AS s2 
ON s1.rowid = s2.rowid 
ORDER BY a;
```

I need to do this a couple of times with different TABLE_As, but TABLE_BC does not change. I could therefore speed things up by creating a temporary in-memory database (mem) for the constant part of the query.

```
CREATE TABLE mem.cache AS 
SELECT rowid, b, c 
FROM main.TABLE_BC 
WHERE (b > 10.0 AND c < 10.0);
```

followed by (many)

```
SELECT a, b, c 
FROM main.TABLE_A 
INNER JOIN mem.cache ON main.TABLE_A.rowid = mem.cache.rowid 
ORDER BY a;
```

I get the same result set from all the queries above, but the last is by far the fastest one.

I would like to avoid splitting the query into two parts. I would expect SQLite to do that automatically (at least in the second scenario), but it does not.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from the [SQLite User Mailing List](http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@sqlite.org/msg60609.html):

> In short, because SQLite cannot read your mind.
>
> To understand the answer compare speeds of executing one query (with
> one TABLE_A) and creating an in-memory database, creating a table in
> it and using that table in one query (with the same TABLE_A). I bet
> the first option (straightforward query without in-memory database)
> will be much faster. So SQLite selects the fastest way to execute your
> query. It cannot predict what the future queries will be to understand
> how to execute the whole set of queries faster. You can do that and
> you should split your query in two parts.
>
> Pavel

Answer (score 3):

SQLite is pretty light on optimization. The general rule of thumb: `SmallTable Inner Join BigTable` is faster than the reverse.

That being said I wonder if your first query would run faster in the following form:

```
SELECT a, b, c 
FROM main.TABLE_A 
  INNER JOIN main.TABLE_BC ON main.TABLE_A.rowid = main.TABLE_BC.rowid 
WHERE (b > 10.0 AND c < 10.0) 
ORDER BY a;
```